# How to change styling of element as scrolling with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there was a way to change styling of the navigation as users scroll down - here is the sample code

```
<div id="navigation">....</div>
<div id="about">....</div>
    <div id="portfolio">....</div>
    <div id="footer">....</div>
```

the #navigation is absolute and so is always at the top of the page. I was wondering if I can show the navigation only when the window is scrolled at the start of each section.

So at the beginning it is visible, when users starts scrolling it fades out, when the #about section is visible the #navigation fades in and fades out as scrolling down.

I tried getting the locations for the #about, #portfolio and #footer this way:

```
margin_top = $("#obsticalSC").css("margin-top");
```

and then have an if statement which says if the top margin of #navigation equals the above, show it. However the above code does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are doing jQuery, this could be of help:

[jQuery scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

this gets the position of the element and how much is it scrolled.

most likely, i guess you are doing one page with dynamic content (displaying one or the other). you can do

```
$("#about").scrollTop();
```

to get how much is scrolled up in the about div or you could change it to:

```
$("body").scrollTop();
```

if you are using the page scrollbars. you can check how much it is scrolled up and do your fade thing.